# The type is not assignable to service autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata, autofac

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface ICategoryFacade
{
    IEnumerable<Category> Get();
    Category Get(int id);
    int Post(Category model);
    int Put(Category model);
    int Patch(Category model);
    int Delete(int id);

}
```

and I have class:

```
public class CategoryFacade : ICategoryFacade
{
    MyContext _dbContext = new MyContext ();

    public IEnumerable<Category> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Categories;
    }
    public Category Get(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(m => m.CategoryID == id);
    }
    public int Post(Category model)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public int Put(Category model)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public int Patch(Category model)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public int Delete(int id)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use IOC with my ODATA Controller. So for doing this I am using following line of code in Global.asax file (Application_Start event):

```
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterInstance(new CategoryFacade()).As<ICategoryFacade>();
        builder.RegisterInstance(new TVideoFacade()).As<ITVideoFacade>();

        builder.RegisterType<CategoryController>();


        //builder.RegisterType<CategoryFacade>().As<ICategoryFacade>();
        //builder.RegisterType<TVideoFacade>().As<ITVideoFacade>();

        //builder.Register(c => new CategoryFacade()).As<ICategoryFacade>().InstancePerRequest();
        //builder.Register(c => new TVideoFacade()).As<ITVideoFacade>().InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

But it showing following exception:

```
Additional information: The type 'ABC.ABCDatabase.Facades.TVideoFacade' is not assignable to service 'ABC.ABCDatabase.Abstractions.ICategoryFacade'.
```

Can you guys tell me what is the proper way to use autofac with OData controller. I am newbie for autofac.

Comment: Does your `TVideoFacade` implement your `ICategoryFacade` interface? I guess this line should be fixed: `builder.RegisterInstance(new TVideoFacade()).As<ICategoryFacade>();` and to be changed to `builder.RegisterInstance(new TVideoFacade()).As<ITVideoFacade>();`

Comment: Yeah this is my mistake but still this showing that exception.

Answer (score 12):

I think you have not implemented ITVideoFacade Interface in TVideoFacade class.
Just go and make sure that u have implemented ITVideoFacade interface in the TVideoFacade class.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks for saving my day

Comment: Woudln't you get a compile time error for this rather than a run time error?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following way to register the **particular type with autofac container**. But make sure your class ABC.ABCDatabase.Facades.TVideoFacade have implemented the interface ABC.ABCDatabase.Abstractions.ICategoryFacade.

```
builder.RegisterType<ABC.ABCDatabase.Facades.TVideoFacade>()
             .As<ABC.ABCDatabase.Abstractions.ICategoryFacade>()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You can set the lifetime and scope according to your business requirements and feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
    builder.Register(x => new TVideoFacade()).As<ITVideoFacade>();
```